# как получить только role_id 2

Tags: postgresql

как получить только role_id = 2 с помощью permission_id 
[image: table]

`SELECT role_id FROM table WHERE permission_id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2])`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что вы уже сделали и что не получилось?

Comment: `SELECT role_id FROM table WHERE permission_id = 1 AND permission_id = 2`

Comment: или `SELECT role_id FROM table WHERE permission_id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2])`

Comment: конечная цель какая? чисто технически можете сделать в запросе max(role_id). Но непонятно что нужно в принципе